# Shopify Grid Product Images disappear

Tags: shopify

HELP PLEASE

The grid product images on the bottom of the page disappear
https://pangeamovement.com/products/pangea-bamboo-travel-towel

Comment: it seems an issue with lazyload JS of your time. it not working properly.

Comment: I took away the lazyload script on theme file but the images still disappear

Comment: That's why it not shown, when you remove the script, you also need to make changes in liquid code to work it properly. current code is done with lazyload and it not work without it.

Comment: I just took away the lazyload script from the product-grid-item.liquid but the images still disappear.
This is the code of that liquid file https://pastebin.com/t4e9Vn39

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10qprw1

Comment: This code need to be edited, if you not want the lazyloading on images.

Comment: what do you think it should be ?

Comment: Thanks! found the solution is to update the lazysizes library to the latest version!

Comment: Great, finally fix it